# form not passing values to PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

I have a responsive website built with a basic contact form. I am trying to use PHPHMailer which I have used in the past. For some reason my values from my form are not making it to the PHPMailer. I tested by placing hard coded values in "name", "email", "subject", and "message" and the form will work without problem. I tried using "isset" to make sure the was value before trying to send the mail (I did this because without the "isset" I get an "undefined index" error which tells me there are no values. This code worked fine on my basic form which was not responsive but not on this one. I am stumped. Any advice would be welcome. here is my code for both the html and the PHP. Thanks! *I have updated the code as I have narrowed the problem down to the Java Script. In the HTML the "form id="main-contact-form" is triggering the following js code

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

It is this js that is causing the issue. I am currently trying to figure out why on this end. Thanks for those that tried to help previously.

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">
    <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my PHP;

```
<?php


        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
        $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];

        require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'myhost.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'me@myemail.com';
        $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

        $mail->From = $email;
        $mail->FromName = $name;
        $mail->addAddress('me@myemail.com');

        $mail->addReplyTo($email);

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $message;

        if(!$mail->send()) {

            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

            exit;
        }        

        echo 'Message has been sent';

?>
```

Comment: Never ever check with submit button value check with posted values directly. `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` the error is here because your submit button has no `name` and `value` attribute

Comment: I tried all the answers, unfortunately they did not work either. I agree with you on never checking the submit button, I think that was out of desperation of nothing else working.

Comment: yes, no errors reported and none in my php log. I am on a live server

Comment: Ask to your server provider that mail settings are properly configured or not on your server?

Comment: yes they are, I can send mail if I enter the values  hard coded in the php, my other sites on that server work with this code with a simple form that is not on this responsive site

Comment: Rather than debugging by trying to check what *should* be there, check what *is* there: stick a `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of your script and then you will be absolutely clear what your form is delivering and can make your code match. Also, don't use the submitter's address as the From address; it's forgery and will cause your messages to be blocked by SPF checks. Instead put your own address in From and their address in reply-to.

Comment: Here is the response:   array(0) {
}
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Message body empty

Answer (score 0):

Check this in your code you are missing this name in submit button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-submit" name='submit'>Send Now</button>
```

and replace this

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

with this

```
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
```

Comment: no errors, the problem is I am getting no values at all passed from my form;    array(0) {
}
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Message body empty

Comment: @JeffReady i have made some changes in answer checkout

Comment: I'm confused, I already have                                                                     $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
        $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];                                                    if you mean for me to add the $POST instead of the $REQUEST, I have tried that as well, That was what I started with, I added $REQUEST because I wasnt getting values and thought that may have been the reason.

Comment: ya replace all variable with $_POST

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue. The solution was pretty simple once I finally figured it out. The main.js template being used does not pass data and type in the ajax code. you need to add type:"POST" and data: form.serialize() to the ajax. see below.

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",//new
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(), //new
            beforeSend: function(){
               form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact
```

you

').